# How to Enable migrations on Visual Studio? Getting an exception when running enable-migrations command

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

I was following a tutorial for code first which is in this link:
https://youtu.be/ZX7_12fwQLU?t=904

I was trying to mix this and a demo for REST API to both things.
My connection string is the one below:

```
    <ConnectionString>
      <add name="RestApiDemo.Models.ProductsDbContext" connectionString=" data source=localhost; initial catalog=RestApiDemo; integrated security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"  ></add>
</ConnectionString>
```

When I run the command enable-migrations in the console it generates the migration folder and file correctly but then I get an exception. This doesn't let me work with Code First despite having generated the file correctly.

The exception is the following:

[Exception screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLWG6.png)

Migrations file generated:

[Migrations File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORYBf.png)

Edit: 
Visual Studio 2017
Framework: 4.6.2

Thank you in advance

Comment: add the version of visual studio, the target framework (eg core, standard) to help us better help you - just saw that tutorial is from April 2017.  things have changed since then so i would avoid using it. have a look in the microsoft docs - they have great stuff there nowdays.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file) documentation page. Check your config file.